# SQL CTE Performance very slow

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a performance problem about Common table expressions in SQL Server. My query  is following

```
;WITH tempCTE (VolumeID,YZMWF,lvl)
    AS
    ( 
        select DISTINCT  VolumeID, YZMWF ,0 as lvl  from YZMDGT where YZMWF=@WorkID
        union  all
        select e.VolumeID, e.YZMWF , cte.lvl + 1 lvl  from YZMDGT e inner join tempCTE cte on e.YZMWF=cte.VolumeID and e.VolumeID<>e.YZMWF

    ) 

    select  DISTINCT * into #dgt from tempCTE
```

It work performance 5 minutes. How to fast to my query? My executing plan following
[image]

Comment: There could be many reasons for that.  Have you run Execution plan results?  It could probably be improved with proper indexes. but if you run Execution Plan and that should give you the big area where you have issues.

Comment: Do you have indexing on YZMWF and VolumeID?

Comment: Also recursion usually takes a lot of time

Comment: Most work seems to be on the index scan.  That would be where to start looking.  Or depending on size of the table, update your logic to return less records (if possible).

Comment: does it make any difference if you move your last join clause: `e.VolumeID<>e.YZMWF` to a `where` clause? it's unlikely to make a massive difference with an inner join as the query optimizer should handle it, but worth trying it.